# Why doesn't the regular expression below work?

Tags: c#, regex, telerik

I'm using data annotation for validation but code below does not work:

```
    [RegularExpression(@"^[0-9]+$", ErrorMessage = "Only Numbers allowed!")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Client Id Required")]
    [Display(Name="Client ID")]
    public int ClientId
    {
       ...}
```

Comment: Anchor it `^[0-9]+$` to avoid windowed matches

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead:

```
[RegularExpression(@"^\d+$", ErrorMessage = "Only numbers allowed")]
```

Answering your question "Why it's not working?", because The `RegexValidator` isn't called when the field is empty, you must use the `RequiredFieldValidator` in combination.

Comment: The RegEx is correct Check it out here : http://www.regexr.com/3ap5q
Are you referencing Unobtrusive JS on your page?

Comment: @Pranav did you try it?